# Why do the pre-defined functions always perform faster then user-defind function for the same functionality? Apologies if its too basic

Tags: programming-languages, user-defined-functions

In every programming languages, why  the  **pre-defined**

functions always performs faster than   **user-defined**

function for the same functionality however we code with minimum Time Complexity?

Is it related to any resource utilization difference of these two types.?

This was my long term query.. I need atleast one better answer..

Answer (score 0):

What you stated is simply not true.  The claim that in *any* language user-defined functions perform worse than builtin is a very bold claim which is to be backed by hard data acquired using profiling.

Being more down-to-Earth though, we indeed might from time to time observe this behaviour with various platforms/lanugages/runtimes/libraries etc.

Mostly this is due to these two reasons:

- Builtin functions are sometimes allowed to not be functions at all: the compiler is free to remove a function call completely (and replace it with something else like a bunch of machine instructions) if the behaviour of the code does not change.

  In C, functions in the `memcpy()` family are a good example of this: in "release" builds, a good compiler for popular platforms usually replaces these cases with direct calls to CPU instructions which copy ranges of memory.
- Builtin functions are often coded in *platform-dependent* assembly, so that when applicable, the function's body will be a finely tuned highly optimized low level code written for the target CPU's extended instruction set (such as SSE and its later iterations on Intel platforms).

If you meant not low-level languages like C but rather more high-level, targetting a virtual machine or interpreted then the answer should be rather more obvious.